# how to use a regex in a factor with r

Tags: r, regex

I have a file A.tsv :

```
Sample
418641
NC
648464
PC
CQ POS 23.09
476844
```

I want to assign a vector with only the value with 100% of integer in it. NC and PC are always present so I remove them easily but for "CQ POS 23.09" it can change like "CQ POS 30.09" so I try some regex.
I try the command:

```
sample_list3=unique(a$Sample)[which( unique(a$Sample) != "NC" & unique(a$Sample) != "PC" & unique(a$Sample) != grep("^QC"),a$Sample)]
```

but I have the error :

```
Error in grep("^QC") : argument "x" is missing
```

Can someone have a different solution than grep ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the values which have only integers in them.

```
result <- as.integer(grep('^\\d+$', a$Sample, value = TRUE))
result
#[1] 418641 648464 476844
```

**data**

```
a <- structure(list(Sample = c("418641", "NC", "648464", "PC", "CQ", 
"POS", "23.09", "476844")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply convert to `numeric` and remove the NA elements

```
na.omit(as.numeric(a$Sample))
```